# Rails, modelling companies / employees relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been thinking about this for a while now, and though it seems simple enough i can't really seem to get it "right". 
What i have, basically, is two classes, Companies and Employees. It is set up so that a Company has_many Employees, and Employees belong_to a Company. Also i use STI, so i have that Company < User and Employee < User. All that is good enough. Now, Employees can only do two things: See their own profile and update it. Companies on the other hand can create employees. In the application this is the only way to create employees. My problem is that i wanna make this as simple as possible, also thinking about that i might make an API at some point. So my question is what is considered good practice here? Should i make Employees a nested resource under Companies? Should i create a Employees resource under a Companies namespace? Should i just keep all actions in the employees_controller and then use permissions to allow companies to acces them? It seems that everything i try ends up feeling "not right".

Answer (score 0):

From what you are asking, there seems to be 2 types of users: The normal user, which is not employee and the employee. Rails has a `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationship between models. So for the company you can do:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :is_employee
   belongs_to : company
```

In the `User` model, there is a column name `is_employee` which stores boolean values. That way, you can have both the employee and non-employee. In the `Company`, if `Company` is destroyed, its `Users` will be gone.

More documentation about those relationship can be found here: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks. I don't really have a problem with making all of this work. As i have it set up now, it works well. My question is more a general Rails question i guess. What should i do to reformulate my original question? Im new here.

Comment: Hmm, back to your question, I am not sure what you mean when you said Only Company can create Employee?

Comment: My problem is that i wanna do this as simple, and "Rails'ish" as possible. So, it's basically about best practices. So, since it doesn't make sense to have an employee without a company, i make employees a nested resource. Now this gives me long and clumsy URLs. So, i split things up. Now my actions for working with employees get scattered over multiple controllers. Also, employees has_many invites, but these are created implicitly and are thus hard to treat as a resource as such. The thing is, im trying to get "the rails way". Maybe i should just make it work though...